# Run bat file as admin remotely in cmd prompt for user on network

Tags: batch-file, cmd, admin, psexec

I've tried uses psexec but all it does is start the process in the background and gives it an ID but doesn't actually do anything.

Attempts:

```
psexec \\pc -h -u org\user -p pass -d -i cmd copy "first_location" "<into_this_locat>"
```

```
psexec \\pc -h -u org\user -p pass command copy "first_location" "<into_this_locat>"
```

It's important that I run this command as an admin otherwise it won't work.

Maybe I can run a .bat file after connecting to their computer as admin?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This is more of a [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

A sustainable way to do this without the need for additional programs to be installed is by using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

If you must run from a cmd.exe shell, the following can be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'SERVER01' -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item -Path "$Env:USERPROFILE\y.y" -Destination "$Env:USERPROFILE\x.x"}"
```